# Variational calculus: finding extremals for a functional

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I have a standard variational problem of the form
$$\mathcal{L}(y)=\int_a^b L[x,y,y^\prime]\mathrm{d}x,$$
where $L[x,y,y^\prime]$ is of the form
$$L[x,y,y^\prime] = y^\prime g(y)$$
for some function $g(\cdot)$ which we can leave unspecified.

With that, the Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation simplifies, using Beltrami, into
\begin{eqnarray} 
\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} &=&L-y^\prime\frac{\partial L}{\partial y^{\prime}}  \nonumber \\
&=& y^\prime g(y)-y^\prime\frac{\partial L}{\partial y^{\prime}} \nonumber \\
&=&  y^\prime g(y)- y^\prime g(y) \nonumber \\
&=& 0 \nonumber 
\end{eqnarray}
But, this should equal a constant. My only conclusion is that I cannot find any  extremals for such $L$, no matter the function $g(y)$. Can someone clarify the situation to me?

---

Some more information:

1. My $g(y)$ contains a Lagrange multiplier as my original problem has a constraint.
2. I have a further constraint that I did not deal with, namely that the solution $y(x)$ must be monotonically increasing.
3. I could provide my $g(y)$, but it appears as the problem with EL for my type of $L$ is general.

If there are no extremals to the original problem, could condition 2 alter this? To me it seems as the answer is negative, since we can incorporate this condition as
$$\tilde{\mathcal{L}}(y)=\int_a^b L[x,y,y^\prime]-\lambda(x)y^{\prime}(x)\mathrm{d}x,$$
so that the problem is still of the form
$$\tilde{L}[x,y,y^\prime]=y^\prime \tilde{g}(y).$$

Comment: Did you notice that $\mathcal{L}(y)=\int_{y(a)}^{y(b)}g(y)dy$ and thus $\mathcal{L}(y)$ only depends on the two values $\{y(a),y(b)\}$?

Comment: Not really....But the outcome of your integral would still depend on $y$...right?

Comment: $\mathcal{L}(y)$ does depend on $y$, but if I'm not wrong it depends only on the value of $y$ at $a$ and $b$. Thus I think that knowing $g$ is not irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, here it comes: $$g(y)=1-\lambda\left[ 1+\left(1-\mathrm{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y}{N}}\right)\right)^2 \right]$$

Comment: Is the aim of the exercise to find the minimum of $\mathcal{L}(y)$?

Comment: a maximum. $\lambda$ is a Lagrange multiplier, $N$ a positive given constant, and $\mathrm{erf}(\cdot)$ the error function.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ costant? Is it positive or negative?

Comment: A Lagrangian multiplier, so once an extremal is found, it must be determined so that $y$ satisfies a constraint (that the integral of the bracketed expression in the fourth comment multiplied with $y^\prime$ equals a specific value).

Comment: Is $y$ allowed to vary at the endpoints, i.e. at $x=a$ and/or at $x=b$?

Comment: There is a side condition that $y(a)=0$, but $y(b)$ is free, and is really what we want to optimize.

Comment: You are right, but what if the magnitude of $y^\prime$ is bounded? In such case $y=\infty$ is not allowed from constraints.

Comment: The fact is that solving only what you have published is easy, but if there are others conditions on $y$ we cannot separate the problems. Thus you should edit the question adding all the requests.

Comment: @FilippoGiovagnini If the integral only depends on the limits of the integration interval, then it means that the function is constant, no?

Comment: @Jose No because $y(b)$ can vary.

Comment: Originally, there are no further constraints. The only thing that can be added if needed is that $y$ should be non-decreasing

Answer (score 2):

When we do a complete calculation we see that the variation only depends on the values at the end points:
$$\begin{align}
\delta \mathcal{L}(y) 
&= \delta \int_a^b y'(x) g(y(x)) \, dx \\
&= \int_a^b \delta y'(x) g(y(x)) \, dx + \int_a^b y'(x)g'(y(x))\delta y(x) \, dx \\
&= \left[ \delta y(x) g(y(x)) \right]_a^b - \int_a^b \delta y(x) g'(y(x)) y'(x))\, dx + \int_a^b y'(x)g'(y(x))\delta y(x) \, dx \\
&= \left[ \delta y(x) g(y(x)) \right]_a^b
.
\end{align}$$

Also, if $G$ is a primitive function of $g,$ then
$$
\mathcal{L}(y) 
= \int_a^b y'(x) g(y(x)) \, dx
= \left[ G(y(x)) \right]_a^b
= G(y(b)) - G(y(a)).
$$
Since $y(a)=0$ we get
$$\mathcal{L}(y)=G(y(b))-G(0).$$
Thus, extremizing $\mathcal{L}(y)$ reduces to finding $y(b)$ that extremizes the above expression. That is, we shall solve
$$
0 = \frac{d}{dy(b)}\left( G(y(b))-G(0) \right) = G'(y(b)) = g(y(b)) \\
= 1-\lambda\left[ 1-\mathrm{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y(b)}{N}}\right)^2 \right]
,
$$
i.e.
$$
\mathrm{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y(b)}{N}}\right) = \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{\lambda}}
.
$$

---

The constraint $\int_0^1 y^\prime[1-\mathrm{erf}^2(\sqrt{y/N})] dx=C,$ where $C$ is a given value, can be written as
$$
\int_a^b y'(x)\,\frac{1-g(y(x))}{\lambda} \, dx = C
$$
i.e.
$$
\left(y(b)-y(a)\right)-\left(G(y(b))-G(y(a))\right) = \lambda C.
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathcal{L}(y)=G(y(b))-G(y(a))=y(b)-y(a)-\lambda C.
$$

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find $y$? The constraint is that $$\int_0^1 y^\prime[1-erf^2(\sqrt{y/N})] dx $$ is a given value.

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake that does not matter much for your answer. the function $g(y)$ I stated was wrong. The corrected version should be $$g(y)=1-\lambda[1-erf^2(\sqrt{y/N})].$$ But this only alters the two last equations of your solution, so the general approach is unaffected

Comment: So the constraint can be written as follows?
$$\int_0^1 y'(x)\,\frac{1-g(y(x))}{\lambda} \, dx = \text{given value}$$

Comment: Is $a=0$ and $b=1$ so that the endpoints for the constraint are the same as for $\mathcal{L}(y)$?

Comment: yes. I obtain\begin{eqnarray} C&=&\frac{N}{2}\mathrm{erf}^2\left(\frac{y(1)}{N}\right)-y(1)\mathrm{erf}^2\left(\frac{y(1)}{N}\right)-\frac{2N\exp(-\frac{y(1)}{N})\sqrt{\frac{y(1)}{N}}\mathrm{erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{y(1)}{N}}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}}\nonumber \\
 &&-\frac{N\exp(-\frac{2y(1)}{N})}{\pi}+y(1)+\frac{N}{\pi} \nonumber
\end{eqnarray} where $C$ is the "given value" so at least a numerical solution can be obtained. Thanks for the help.